# Changing tserver_master_addrs in YugabyteDB without restarting?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

The docs on [changing cluster config](https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/manage/change-cluster-config/#6-update-master-addresses-on-tservers), indicate that, when changing yb-master cluster membership, yb-tserver tserver_master_addrs should be updated to reflect the latest list of nodes, but I don't see a clear indication of how to best do so.  Is this only possible by terminating each yb-tserver process and rerunning it with a new command-line flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [yb-ts-cli set_flag](https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/admin/yb-ts-cli/#set-flag) for updating flags during runtime.

In this case, the tserver learns the new master addresses at runtime by itself, you just need to update the yb-tserver config so it has the new masters if it gets restarted.

Also, string flags in general are not safe to change at runtime because they're not thread-safe.